# running specific test case with python unittest in django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, python-unittest, wagtail

I have a set of unit tests that I can successfully run with: `./runtests.py wagtail.wagtailcore.tests`

I can also run:

```
./runtests.py wagtail.wagtailcore.tests.test_page_privacy
```

But if I want to execute just one of them, I get an error that `'module' object has no attribute [test_case_name]`

My class would be something like:

```
class TestPagePrivacy(TestCase):
  def test_anonymous_user_must_authenticate(self):
```

so I would think you could just say: `./runtests.py wagtail.wagtailcore.tests.test_page_privacy.test_anonymous_user_must_authenticate`

Why doesn't this work?

From the django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests

```
# Run just one test method
$ ./manage.py test animals.tests.AnimalTestCase.test_animals_can_speak
```

Comment: i guess you need put testcase class name in between

Comment: Sorry, ammended my post - that doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the answer is:

```
./runtests.py wagtail.wagtailcore.tests.test_page_privacy.TestPagePrivacy.test_anonymous_user_must_authenticate
```

So - directory / file name / class name / test name

Comment: This gives me the output `Ran 0 tests`, using Django 2.2.0.

Comment: @Igettäjä The module paths changed in Wagtail 2 - the equivalent command is now: `./runtests.py wagtail.core.tests.test_page_privacy.TestPagePrivacy.test_anonymous_user_must_authenticate`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
wagtail.wagtailcore.tests.TestPagePrivacy.test_anonymous_user_must_authenticate
```